Can you equip or unequip a weapon before or after a Bonus Action?
Using the Bonus Action mentioned in the Light property as an example, is that Bonus Action considered part of the Attack Action for the purpose of equipping or unequipping the weapon before or after the Bonus Action attack?


Attack [Action]
When you take the Attack action, you can make
one attack roll with a weapon or an Unarmed Strike.
Equipping and Unequipping Weapons. You can either equip or unequip one
weapon when you make an attack as part of this action. You do so
either before or after the attack. If you equip a weapon before an
attack, you don’t need to use it for that attack. Equipping a weapon
includes drawing it from a sheath or picking it up. Unequipping a
weapon includes sheathing, stowing, or dropping it.


Light
When you take the Attack action on your turn and attack
with a Light weapon, you can make one extra attack as a Bonus Action
later on the same turn. That extra attack must be made with a
different Light weapon, and you don’t add your ability modifier to the
extra attack’s damage unless that modifier is negative. For example,
you can attack with a Shortsword in one hand and a Dagger in the other
using the Attack action and a Bonus Action, but you don’t add your
Strength or Dexterity modifier to the damage roll of the Bonus Action
unless that modifier is negative.


No.
From the Free Rules (2024) Glossary:

A Bonus Action is a special action that you can take on the same turn that you take an action.

ie, it is separate from the action you made the Attack Action with.

No
The key part of the rules for the attack action you've quoted are the following (emphasis mine) :

You can either equip or unequip one weapon when you make an attack as part of this action.

The equiping/unequiping can only be done when you make an attack that is part of the Attack action.
When you use your bonus action to attack with a light weapon, you are not taking the Attack action. The fact that those two interactions are dissociated from one another is made clearer by the text you quoted from the Light property rules (emphasis mine) :

When you take the Attack action on your turn and attack with a Light weapon, you can make one extra attack as a Bonus Action later on the same turn.

As such, the bonus action attack does not allow you to equip or unequip a weapon when you make that attack.
